# DiscordJS -> Formatting message like server join

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on an emote bot for our text chat channels. I have it kind of working. The goal is that if a user types something like:

~hug @user

The bot sweeps up the message, removes it, and then emotes to the chat room:

| Joe hugs Jane.  Awww!

This is working, but I'm using embed with a red border on the left side to make it look special. However this shows as a message from the bot, with the avatar picture, bot name, and such. What I'd like to do is have emotes show up without the bot name and such, like the announcement format when someone joins a server, etc.

Any advice on how to send a message formatted like that to a channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately sending any messages that look like system messages, such as `RECIPIENT_ADD`, `RECIPIENT_REMOVE`, `CALL`, `CHANNEL_NAME_CHANGE`, `CHANNEL_ICON_CHANGE`, `PINS_ADD` or `GUILD_MEMBER_JOIN` is not possible using a Discord Bot.

This is a limitation of Discord itself and **not** a limitation of discord.js

You could, however, try to achieve a similar-ish looking result by using a webhook with a blank Avatar and Username.

```
message.channel.createWebhook('/*Webhook Name*/', "/*Webhook Avatar URL*/")
.then(w => w.send("your message here"));
```

Comment: Yeah that at least lets me set the name to EMOTE and such, so it's better